# aws opensearch bulk insert enquiry

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

i am a beginner in aws opensearch.I have one important question regarding it that is
how much data(in MB or GB) i can insert in bulk at a single time in aws opensearch.
i tried to find solution of my question on aws website but couldn't get the answer please let me know if you can help

Answer (score 2):

The amount of data you can insert using the bulk operations will depend on the cluster, configuration and data (among other factors) but I've found this to be a good [recommendation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/opensearch-indexing-performance/):

"Start with the bulk request size of 5 MiB to 15 MiB. Then, slowly increase the request size until the indexing performance stops improving."